# How to fix pagination in custom taxonomy of a custom post type page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a loop on my taxonomy.php page, and I need a pagination on it. I use the same pagination as in other places. On other pages the pagination works fine, but on the taxonomy it doesn't work if I click 2-3-4-etc pages. It shows 404.
Adding this code to functions didn't help

```
function taxonomy_rewrite_fix($wp_rewrite) {
    $r = array();
    foreach($wp_rewrite->rules as $k=>$v){
        $r[$k] = str_replace('catalog=$matches[1]&paged=','catalog=$matches[1]&page=',$v);
    }
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $r;
}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'taxonomy_rewrite_fix');
```

My taxonomy loop code

```
    $al_cat_slug = get_queried_object()->slug;
    $al_cat_name = get_queried_object()->name;?>
       <div class="book-items row">            
    <?php
global $post;   
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$args = array ( 
    'post_type' => 'book',
    'sortby'=>'name', 
    'caller_get_posts'=>1,
    'posts_per_page'=> 2,
    'paged'=>$paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'book-categories',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $al_cat_slug
                )
            )
);
query_posts( $args );

if ( have_posts() ):
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();?>

     <div class="book-item col-12">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>">
        <h2 class="book-title">
            <?php if( get_field('catalog_order') ): ?>
            <span class="catalog-order"><?php the_field('catalog_order')?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php if( get_field('book_author') ): ?>
            <span class="book-author"> — <?php the_field('book_author')?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
            </h2> 
        </a>    
    </div>

<?php    endwhile;
echo the_posts_pagination();    
endif;

wp_reset_query();?>        
     </div>
```

2 is simply for example, to see how it works. What could help with that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you flush your permalinks?

Also, beter to alter your taxonomy archive via a `pre_get_posts` and use https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/ plugin instead of coding basic stuff like this yourself.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/#description also talks about using `pre_get_posts`.